# Center-align the verbatim environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats, verbatim

I am trying to center align the content of a figure that has verbatim text in it. But the verbatim text is always right-aligned:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{verbatim}
  some
  text
  here
  \end{verbatim}
  \caption{I wish this were centered}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A `verbatim` environment is always typeset on full length. You may want to look at the `fancyvrb` package and its `BVerbatim` environment.

Comment: @cam Don't forget to select the answer if it worked for you. Points for having their answer selected helps motivate people to continue to answer questions. If it didn't work, perhaps you can provide additional details, or submit your own answer if you came up with another solution.

Comment: @egreg - I tried `BVerbatim`, but it seems that `boxwidth=auto` doe not work correctly but always yields the full page width. I have to specify an explicit dimension in order for the centering to work. Any clues on this? I would prefer `BVerbatim` if this worked.

Comment: @EmitTaste same issue here. I used xleftmargin and xrightmargin to adjust it manually, also vspace does conflict with fancyvrb environments. :/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [verbatimbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6x1E.jpg) package also does this.  Here's an example done that way (Fig. 1).

UPDATE: In Fig. 2, it is shown how you can import multiple verbatim snippets into a single figure (or table) using the `myverbbox` environment, wherein you give unique names to the snippets.  Also, the optional argument can be used to condition the verbatim text, in this case, to `\small`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}
  some \verbatim
  text here
\end{verbbox}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \theverbbox
  \caption{I wish this were centered}
\end{figure}

\begin{myverbbox}[\small]{\valph}\alpha\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}[\small]{\vbet}\beta\end{myverbbox}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\valph & $\alpha$\\
\vbet  & $\beta$
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some Greek macros for math mode}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do I have to define the box outside the figure?

Comment: @einpoklum It can be use inside the `figure`, but then it is not available outside of *that* `figure`.  Also, it cannot be used inside the `tabular`