# How to center verbatim

Tags: horizontal-alignment, verbatim

```
\begin{figure}
\centerline
\begin{verbatim}
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
  for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) 
    ...
\end{verbatim}
\caption{C++ code}
\end{figure}
```

I would like the figure to be centered, so I include `\centerline`. But this induces an error. How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to use [\centering](http://www-hermes.desy.de/latex/ltx-209.html), not \centerline.

Comment: @MMA I replaced \centerline with \centering, but the text is still aligned to the left.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98170/center-verbatim-text-in-figure/99940#99940.  It puts verbatim in a box.  Then you can center it.

Answer (score 27):

You can do this using the [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package features; in this case, the `BVerbatim` environment which boxes the verbatim material:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{BVerbatim}
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
  for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) 
    ...
\end{BVerbatim}
\caption{C++ code}
\end{figure}
\noindent A\hrulefill B% just for visual guide

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you do it without figure?

Comment: @Miro Sure; you can use `center` instead of `figure`, suppress the `\centering` and use `\captionof` to provide the caption. I just kept the original settings of the OP.

Answer (score 12):

The following solution is based on package [`varwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varwidth):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{verbatim}
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
  for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
    ...
\end{verbatim}
\end{varwidth}
\caption{C++ code}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With the help of package [`verbatim`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) this can also be put in a new environment definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newenvironment{centerverbatim}{%
  \par
  \centering
  \varwidth{\linewidth}%
  \verbatim
}{%
  \endverbatim
  \endvarwidth
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{centerverbatim}
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
  for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
    ...
\end{centerverbatim}
\caption{C++ code}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```