# How to use block/box drawing characters in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, symbols

How can I use the Unicode [block character elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements) like `█` in LaTeX?

When I just add/paste them like they are, they are, for some reason, omitted.

My use case is to "draw" a simple black/white "image"/ASCII art, like in old-school console terminals.

Actually using lualatex, in case that helps. The file is UTF-8 encoded. The font package I use is `lmodern`.

The same question (and likely answer) also applies/works for [box drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character).

To get in more details, here is a short code snippet I use:

```latex
\begin{equation}
    \setlength{\jot}{-12pt}
    \begin{aligned}
    test123
            \\
     ███    \\
     █ █ █  \\
     ███    \\
          █ \\
    █    █  \\
     █  █   \\
     ███    \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

It does not "render" though:
[image: PDF not being rendered, source code showing image is fine]

Comment: You can simply use the `\rule` command with suitable parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

1. `lualatex` or `xelatex`;
2. a font that supports "block elements", such as `LucidaConsole`;
3. `verbatim`, rather than math to set the result.
4. Set baselineskip to match fontsize, so that no vertical gap appears in your block drawings
5. Scope your code appropriately, so that you can embed these inside a normally formatted document.

The revised MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Testing
{
\setmonofont{LucidaConsole}
\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}
\begin{verbatim}
    test123

     ███    
     █ █ █  
     ███    
          █ 
    █    █  
     █  █   
     ███    
\end{verbatim}
}
Testing
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay uhm, thx. Now I still try to center it (just like `equation` did), but just putting it in a `center` environment or adding `\centering` does not work.

Comment: Okay how to do this has been answered in [How to center verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122195/98645).