# boxed verbatim environment disappears

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, verbatim

I want to center a box containing a verbatim environment. The (almost)MWE below is my attempt to use the answer at 
[Center-align the verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98170/center-verbatim-text-in-figure/99940#99940) .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
The table at \verb!http://www.census.gov/govs/state/10lottery.html!
lists the following data for the 2010 Texas lotteries:

\begin{center}
\begin{verbbox}
  Income               Apportionment of funds
(ticket sales      Prizes  Administration  Proceeds
  excluding                               available
  commissions)
  3,542,210       2,300,182   184,980     1,057,048
\end{verbbox}
\end{center}

Since
%
\begin{equation*}
\frac{2,300,182}{3,542,210} = 0.649363533 \approx 65\%
\end{equation*}
%
Texas returned 65 cents on the dollar in lottery payouts in 2010 --
three cents more than the national average.

\end{document}
```

In the output, the boxed text has disappeared:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to issue `\theverbbox` in order to print the verbatim text. However, the `verbbox` environment shouldn't be inside `center`.

I also add how to do it with `fancyvrb` and its `BVerbatim` environment. I also use `\url` for the URL.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,fancyvrb,url}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The table at \url{http://www.census.gov/govs/state/10lottery.html}
lists the following data for the 2010 Texas lotteries:
\begin{verbbox}
  Income               Apportionment of funds
(ticket sales      Prizes  Administration  Proceeds
  excluding                               available
  commissions)
  3,542,210       2,300,182   184,980     1,057,048
\end{verbbox}
\begin{center}
\theverbbox
\end{center}

Since
\begin{equation*}
\frac{2,300,182}{3,542,210} = 0.649363533 \approx 65\%
\end{equation*}
Texas returned 65 cents on the dollar in lottery payouts in 2010 --
three cents more than the national average.

\begin{center}
\begin{BVerbatim}
  Income               Apportionment of funds
(ticket sales      Prizes  Administration  Proceeds
  excluding                               available
  commissions)
  3,542,210       2,300,182   184,980     1,057,048
\end{BVerbatim}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew about `\url` but omitted to minimize my example. I know about using `\centering` instead of a `center` environment for figures. Why not use it here?

Comment: @EthanBolker With `center` you leave some vertical space fore and aft the verbatim part. This is the reason why `\centering` should be preferred in a `figure` or `table` environment, but not here.

Comment: I see. The `\verbbox` is defined  _outside_ the `center` environment but the `\theverbox` is _inside_.

Comment: @EthanBolker If it's inside, the last line disappears.

Comment: I noticed! I find that weird. I'm sure digging into source would explain why, but that's more than I need to know.