# Add verbatim code to longtable caption

Tags: longtable, verbatim

I'd like to add a caption containing verbatim characters using `\verb` to a long table using the package longtable.

The reason for this is that I want to improve the LaTeX output of [pandoc](http://pandoc.org), which uses longtable to typeset tables and fancyvrb for code highlighting.

Currently, when I use code highlighting in a figure or table caption in pandoc, the generated LaTeX code complains about the verbatim code inside a caption.
However, I found the package cprotect designed for allowing verbatims in section headers, captions and alike. Therefore, I added the package and a `\cprotect` in front of both captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cprotect}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
Here comes a figure.
\cprotect\caption{This is the caption with \verb+verbatim+.}
\end{figure}

\begin{longtable}{c}
\cprotect\caption{This is the caption with \verb+verbatim+.}
\tabularnewline
\hline
This is the content with \verb+verbatim+.
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, pdflatex now complains

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\caption ->\noalign 
                    \bgroup \@ifnextchar [{\egroup \LT@c@ption \@firstofone ...
l.13 ...This is the caption with \verb+verbatim+.}
```

So `\cprotect` works for the figure caption, but not for the table's one. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is `\texttt{verbatim}` out of question?

Comment: In principle, `\texttt{code}` would also work. But because pandoc normally translates higlighted code into `\VERB|code|`, where `\VERB` is defined as `\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]` from fancyvrb, it would be nice to reuse it. If this is not possible (or at least not that easy), I can of course translate highlighted code in caption and headers into `\texttt{...}` and escape the special LaTeX characters.

Comment: Perhaps an approach like this, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98170/center-align-the-verbatim-environment/99940#99940, would work.

Comment: Hi Steven, thank you for your advice. I can indeed use your solution to put verbatim code into a longtable caption, that is great! Unfortunately, the verbatim part contains some code highlighting macros, such as `\NormalTok{f }\FunctionTok{<*>} \DataTypeTok{Just} \DecValTok{42}`, which are also output verbatim. Based on your advice I had a look at `\SaveVerb` and `\UseVerb` from the fancyvrb package, but this does not work for longtable captions at all. Do you have any further advise?