# Why does a verbatim block produce an error when it is used inside a table?

Tags: tables, verbatim

The following script

```
14 \begin{tabular}{ l }
15  \begin{verbatim}
16    $\mathcal{M A T H C A L}$
17    $\mathfrak{M A T H F R A C}$
18  \end{verbatim}
19 \end{tabular}
```

produces an error:

```
Line 15: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

The same verbatim block works fine outside the table. Why not in it?

Comment: `l` is a single line entry you want a column type like `p{3cm}` or somesuch

Comment: If retaining the column type as `l` is essential, then there are other ways to get verbatim into the `tabular`.  For example, see my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98170/center-align-the-verbatim-environment/99940#99940

Comment: David: Replacing 'l' with p{?cm} works, even if ? = 0!  Thanks. 

Steven: Yes, 'verbbox' works too. Thanks.